# Cannot get array value after pre_match with PHP function

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable which contain a line of string. I want to build a function to filter the string by using the regular expression. I want to filter the string which are of the form like "_{text_one or text_tow}". Exactly in this example of mine you can see there are two "_{text_one} and _{text_two}". I want my function return them as an array `["_{text_one}","_{text_two}"]`.

I have tried to use array_shift() function, but it return only one.

```
$text = 'L\' utente _{text_one} _{text_tow} ti ha invitato a giocare';
$text_vars = preg_match('#\_{(.*?)\}#', $text, $matches);
$temp = array_shift( $matches );
```

Could anyone give me the function that can get both of them as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `preg_match()` to `preg_match_all()`

```
$text = 'L\' utente _{text_one} _{text_tow} ti ha invitato a giocare';
$text_vars = preg_match_all('#\_{(.*?)\}#', $text, $matches);
$temp = array_shift( $matches );

var_dump($temp);
```

**Output**:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
    string(11) "_{text_one}"
  [1]=>
    string(11) "_{text_tow}"
}
```